# Java MySQL missing driver?

Tags: java, mysql, driver

I'm trying to make my program read/write in a database. I found this sample code to connect which compiles without problems:

"http://webhelp.ucs.ed.ac.uk/services/mysql/example2-java.php"

but Im having issues running it. Whenever I execute I get

```
Failed to load mysql driver
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

Do I need to download the driver manually and supply it through classpath or is it already given in java?

**EDIT** Alright, so I downloaded the driver but how can I run it with classpath to use the driver? I got this as my batch command but it gives me an error:

```
java -classpath driver/mysql.jar MySQL
```

and the error is

```
Error: Could not find or load main class MySQL
```

While without the classpath it finds the MySQL class :S

**EDIT** FIGURED IT OUT :D

```
java -cp .;./driver/mysql.jar MySQL
```

Comment: Yes, you have to download the required JAR file(s). In other words those that contain the class/interface `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`. It's not part of the JDK/JRE itself.

Comment: Yes, downloading the MYSQL driver and putting it in your classpath is exactly what you need to do.

Comment: Are you using eclipse? Knowing which IDE you are using or if you are using one will help us answer question

Comment: nope, not using any IDEs, just notepad and batch to compile/run. This is my command to run it but i dont think it's correct.
`java -classpath driver/mysql.jar MySQL` and the driver is in the "driver" folder.

Comment: Try including you current location in your classpath. For example: java -classpath .:driver/mysql.jar MySQL

Comment: unfortunately still gives me Error: `Could not find or load main class MySQL`. It doesnt give me this error when i don't include the classpath but then it gives me the driver one of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[You need to download it.](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/)  I would add it to a `lib/` directory (in your project) and add that directory to your classpath.

Comment: Yah, im coding old school lol, notepad and batch, so i guess ill add it to the batch